# Text being clipped in sidebar inside of a jquery easy ticker element IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using this plugin https://github.com/vaakash/jquery-easy-ticker . It works as expected in all browsers except Internet Explorer (go figure). The main problem even seen in IE11 is that the image and text are clipped on the right side of the sidebar. Any ideas?

Comment: Problem exists in Firefox, too, FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you could solve the problem by setting `width: 100%` to the `<ul>` inside the ticker div.

```
<div id="tickerMember" >
    <ul class="list-unstyled" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: That fixed it, I sent a note to the plugin developer to add that is his JS.